# Swagger-ui 2.0 path do not get Bearer Authorization from top

Tags: node.js, express, swagger-ui, bearer-token

when I check on swagger , my path "/customers" says "no headers authorization" whereas I have entered a Bearer token into the top right "Authorize" input. It is like the customers "security" prop is not linked to general securityDefinitions. In web Swagger, the padlock near GET /Customers is grey and open, when I click on it it does not show any "available authorization".(Postman version is working), I can't find why, could you help me please ?

In my swagger-ui (2.0)json file I got :

```
"securityDefinitions": {
    "Bearer": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "Authorization",
      "in": "header",
      "description": "Enter your bearer token in the format **Bearer &lt;token>**"
    }
  },
```

then below on the second path I entered "security" :

```
"/customers": {
      "get": {
        "tags": ["Customer Search"],
        "summary": "find a customer by email, name, tel, ...",
        "security": [{ "bearerAuth": [] }],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "email",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "email",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "realmCode",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "realmCode",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "send customer json file"
          }
        }
```

Here is the beginning of my node Express JS code for my route :

````
router.get("/customers", async (req: any, res: any) => {
  if (!req.headers.authorization)
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "no headers authorization" });
  else {
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I found it :

```
  "security": [{ "Bearer": [] }],
```

instead of "bearerAuth" :)

Comment: Thanks bro! You asked and solved it at the same time hahaha!